# Finding the no of occurence of a string inside another string using regex in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I want to find the no of occurences of a sustring(pattern based) inside another string.
For example:

```
$mystring = "|graboard='KERALA'||graboarded='KUSAT'||graboard='MG'";
```

I want to find the no of `graboard`s present in the `$mystring`,

So I used the regex for this, But how will I find the no of occurrence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must use a regex, `preg_match_all()` returns the number of matches.

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_match_all`:

```
$mystring = "|graboard='KERALA'||graboarded='KUSAT'||graboard='MG'";

preg_match_all("/(graboard)='(.+?)'/i", $mystring, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

will yield:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => graboard='KERALA'
            [1] => graboard='MG'
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => graboard
            [1] => graboard
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => KERALA
            [1] => MG
        )

)
```

So then you can use `count($matches[1])` -- however, this regex may need to be modified to suit your needs, but this is just a basic example.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`preg_match_all()`](https://www.php.net/preg_match_all):

```
// The string.
$mystring="|graboard='KERALA'||graboarded='KUSAT'||graboard='MG'";

// The `preg_match_all()`.
preg_match_all('/graboard/is', $mystring, $matches);

// Echo the count of `$matches` generated by `preg_match_all()`.
echo count($matches[0]);

// Dumping the content of `$matches` for verification.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```